# My css , js , and images stop working when I use node server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

main_page.html

```
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
       <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       
       <a class="counselor" href="">
           <img src="img/icons/counselor.svg" alt="counselor" title="Counselor">
       </a>
       <!-- <a class="application" href="http://localhost:5500">
           <img src="img/icons/application.svg" alt="application" title="Apply for Colleges">
       </a> -->
   
       <section class="main-page">
   
           <header class="header">
               <div class="logo">
                   <a href="main-page.html"><img src="img/icons/logo-b.svg" alt="logo"></a>
               </div>
               <div class="header-items">
                   <a href="pick-course.html" id="header-engi" >Engineering</a>
                   <a href="pick-course.html">Medical</a>
                   <a href="pick-course.html">Business</a>
                   <a href="pick-course.html">Law</a>
                   <a href="pick-course.html">Design</a>
                   <a href="pick-course.html">Science</a>
                   <a href="application_main.html" class="application_main">Application</a>
               </div>
           </header>
   
           <h2 class="heading2">A place to find your dream college</h2>
           <img class="img img-1" src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="bg1">
           <img class="img img-2" src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="bg2">
           <img class="img img-3" src="img/bg3.jpg" alt="bg3">
           <img class="img img-4" src="img/bg4.jpg" alt="bg4">
           <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for college">
           <a href="" class="search-icon" ><img src="img/icons/search.svg" alt="searchicon"></a>
       </section>
  
   
   
    <script src="main-page.js"></script>   
    
   </body>
   </html>
```

application.js

```
const express=require("express")
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const bodyParser=require("body-parser")

const app=express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/StudentData",{useNewUrlParser:true},{useUnifiedTopology:true})

const studentSchema={
    name:String,
    dob:String,
    gender:String,

}

const Student=mongoose.model("Student",studentSchema)

app.get('/main-page.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/main-page.html")
})

app.get('/application_main.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/application_main.html")
})
app.get('/application.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/application.html')
})

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    let student= new Student({
    name:req.body.name,
    dob:req.body.dob,
    gender:req.body.gender,
    })
    student.save()
    res.redirect('/application.html')
})

app.listen(8080,()=>{
    console.log("Server on ")
})
```

When I add the get request for `main-page.html` and go to `localhost:8080/main-page.html`, only the HTML shows, my images  have broken, the CSS file does not apply and an effect I had done `main-page.js` doesn't work. How can I fix it? All my paths are correct.

For CSS it shows the following error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

For images:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

And the `main-page.js` file, which had basic JS code (`eventlistener` and `querySelector` etc) just doesn't work.

Comment: You might need a ./ in the file path. when running as a http web serve, it is relative to the folder that is being served. the "./" means look in the same folder. e.g. you may need to do "./css/style.css"

Comment: fyi, you dont need the body-parser package anymore, use `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))` instead

Comment: @Alvie Mahmud  tried it , didn't  work.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared your static assets - CSS, JavaScript from Express. I guess you need to have a dedicated folder say, `static` or something and put everything there.

```
+ static
| + css
| ` - style.css
...
```

And you need to serve them using [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

```js
express.static(root, [options])
```

If you have created the above directory, then you can do:

```js
app.use(express.static('static'))
```

And you will be able to get all the files in that directory. Example:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

Comment: I'ma try it and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @ResinDeo Sure, I have also added the link to the documentation, if you're stuck. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a folder with name public and include all your css and images in this folder then write this line of code in your `app.js` file

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```